# How to make a Javascript/jQuery/HTML animated stack of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-animate

I want to make a javascript/jQuery/HTML based image viewer which is sort of a cross between a book page flip and an iTunes coverflow interface without the left side of either, which would work on mobile device browsers.

I've been looking for tutorials which I can use as a starting point, but I haven't been able to find anything yet.  Can anybody offer some advice on how to get started on this project?  I would like to be able to come up with a rough mock up pretty quickly so it would be helpful to be able to re-use code from a tutorial or existing open-source project.

Comment: [**Check this out**](http://www.turnjs.com/#), this will really help you in terms of your requirement. It has backward compatibility as well and also works on small devices.

Comment: something like this using Iscroll -- http://jsfiddle.net/8BUjf/2/

Comment: try a plugin. Or you could try a css animation.

Comment: @Veer -- I was actually looking at that one already, it does look promising.

Comment: I think [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What about [pagePiling.js plugin](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/)?

It creates a **stack of pages** and on it you can add images if you want, just like [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/examples/backgrounds.html).

And of course, you can use it [horizontally](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/examples/horizontalScroll.html) if you prefer.